# How to avoid MessageDialog in Page Navigation

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-async

In my application hitting service call on every page navigation and showing MessageDialog to user.

My problem was when I hitting service call (await) on page navigation "Page1" to "Page2" whereas service call taking certain time to complete meantime user taps back to "Page1"

In that case user seeing "Page1" and await service call completed on "Page2" and showing that service response message in "Page1".

How can I avoid MessageDialog suppose user navigates back from that page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid using MessageDialogs for this sort of information.  You should think about using a ProgressBar or ring to indicate that your app is performing a task in the background (calling your service).  This way, your users won't be interrupted in their interactions with the app, yet still be aware that something is going on in the background.

If you are using an MVVM pattern, your ViewModel or Model classes should be doing the heavy lifting of talking to the service.  If your app absolutely must show MessageDialogs, I'd recommend creating an event in your back-end classes that will cause the UI to show the MessageDialogs on completion of the call.  That way you can subscribe to those events when you load the page, and unsubscribe from them when you navigate away.  In this way you can avoid messages appearing from Page2 when you are on Page1 of your app.

Comment: I'm showing multiple user ids in the gridview on "Page1". User tapping on "User1" in "Page1" and app redirecting to "Page2" and hitting the service (async) and showing "User1" informations.

Problem occurring below scenario

User on "Page1" tapping on "User1" app redirection to "Page2" hitting service (async) for getting "User1" information. Meantime, user navigate back to "Page1" and clicked on another User "User3" 

whereas app on "page2" but that time "User1" service call is completed and showing his information on Page2 actually it should showing "User3" information.

Comment: So where did the "MessageDialog" part of your original question come from?